# SaveState and LoadState in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Pretty nice thing in VisualStudio's default template is LayoutAwarePage. We can SaveState and LoadState of the pages in Application navigation and Termination. In this case, I have 'n' number of ComboBoxes and TextBoxes inside the RootGrid.

While navigating to NextPage i am saving the RootGrid's State using the following code.

```
pageState.Add("RootGridPage",RootGrid);
```

I have written the code by the guess like , LayoutAwarePage will take care of the Serialization for all the controls available in the RootGrid rather than Serializing only the RootGrid.

When i try to get the RootGrid in the LoadState method using the following code.

```
if (pageState !=null && pageState.ContainsKey("RootGridPage"))
            {
                RootGrid= pageState["RootGridPage"] as Grid;
            }
```

I did not get the Deserialized ComboBoxes and TextBoxes in the RootGrid. It did not persist the state. My question is whether if we save the State of the RootGrid, will it save all the available states of the controls inside it ?. If it is not, Is there any way to achieve this ?. Because i cant go and save the state for the all the 'n' number of controls.
Could you please anyone help me on this ?

Comment: need to bind the grid to view model. All properties in view model that are part of session state -- can be added to pageState in load/savestate methods